# redhat + how to download rpm from red-hat site

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

I need to down load the following rpm from red-hat formal site

```
    kernel-debuginfo-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64
```

is it possible to use the following rpm command for download ?

```
rpm --import http://....
```

if yes the how ( what is the syntax and path ) ?

other approach:

```
  root@test:~ # yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp kernel-debuginfo
  Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
  This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
   No package kernel-debuginfo available.
   Error: Nothing to do

 root@test:~ # yumdownloader  kernel-debuginfo
 Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin
 This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
 No Match for argument kernel-debuginfo
 Nothing to download
```

Comment: Do you have an authorized (paid for) redhat subscription?  Then from my recollection you should be able to use yum.  Otherwise you might want to connect to the Centos repositories to get what you want.

Comment: yes I have , I am also connected to RHN but I want to use the rpm command in order to download only one rpm from the formal site

Comment: I want to download only from the redhat formal site

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-rpm-using.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have redhat subscription then the answer is described [at this page](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154).

Option 1. Preparation (one-time activity):

```
(RHEL5)
# yum install yum-downloadonly

(RHEL6+)
# yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
```

Option 1. Actual usage:

```
# yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>
```

Option 2. Preparation:

```
# yum install yum-utils
```

Option 2. Actual usage:

```
# yumdownloader <package>
```

If you don't have subscription you should consider Centos as an alternative option.

Comment: is redhat 6 version command syntax is the same as redhat 7 ( I have redhat 7 version )

Comment: yes, it should be so. I've updated the answer.

Comment: hi rush , please see my update - why I get - No package kernel-debuginfo available?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple!

You can utilize YUM or DNF to download and install the RPM.

Example:

- yum install http://redhat/package.rpm
- dnf install http://redhat/package.rpm

Answer (score 0):

As you explicitly ask about a `-debuginfo` package, see the verified RedHat knowledgebase article
[How can I download or install debuginfo packages for RHEL systems?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9907)
which additionally has some information on how to check your RHN subscriptions or subscription-manager channels.